# Why doesn't jupiter look bigger than our moon?

Tags: the-moon, jupiter, earth

If Jupiter is 365 million miles away from earth. Our moon is about 238,900 miles away from earth. that means Jupiter is 1527.8 times farther away from the earth than the moon. Jupiter is 5285.2 times bigger than our moon. now thinking, if the moon was twice as far away as it is now, shouldn't it look twice as small? now thinking of it that way. shouldn't Jupiter look 3.5 times the size of our moon? with Jupiter being 5285.2 times bigger than our moon but 1527.8 times farther away from the earth than the moon. math wise Jupiter should be 3.5 times the size of our moon. so way isn't it? am i over looking something?

Comment: The diameter of Jupiter is 142,984 km, the Moon is 3,476 km, that is a ratio of 41.13. You should not compare the volume or the mass to determine which body should look bigger. It is only a matter of diameter and distance. I think you can write an answer to your own question now.

Comment: `+1` You've done a space-related calculation, then made and independent check of your work and found an apparent disagreement. So you've come to SXSE, joined, and posed your work, including all the numerical values you've used as well as your assumptions, and asked for assistance - this is a model question!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is pure Astronomy, not Space Exploration

Comment: If it's pure astronomy it should be migrated, not closed.

Comment: thank you Uwe. i completely over looked that. my bad on that. yes using your numbers it makes since. thank you for the help